# Nginx backslash not supported for proxy_pass (use as a reverse proxy)?

Tags: nginx, xmlhttprequest, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to host a 3rd party rather advanced Java app thru Wildfly using NGINX.

I've tried the following things (please check out the commented out config too)

```
location /app {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/app;
            proxy_redirect off;
            
            #rewrite ^/$uri $uri break;
            #rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
        }

        #location ^~ /app/*\\ {
        #    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/app/*\\;
        #}
```

When I go to my hostname/app I can see the complicated Java Web App and login, but when it needs to load some documents it throws out the following XHR error (500 for this URL, but it's actually just 404):

```
https://example.org/app/app/resource/templateTree/\?count=200&orderBy=-1&orderDirectionAscending=false&fldrTime=-1&hash=53cdac085761b1a3fb5ba4535c8edf85e91c2f
```

How do I properly rewrite this URL with the backslash? That's exactly what I've tried in the config below, but failed miserably.

The server block itself is defined fine, just under location the rewriting should be added. When I run the application on `localhost` (without NGINX) I get the following URL in the XHR request, which succeeds:

```
http://10.0.2.4:8080/app/app/resource/document/home/%5C?count=200&orderBy=-1&orderDirectionAscending=false&fldrTime=0
```

`proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/app$uri;` doesn't work at all apparently :(

Answer (score 0):

Wow, all I had to do was remove the `/app` in `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080`.

Case closed

**bangs hammer**